# What maneuvers can be employed to shake a jet from my six?

Tags: battlefield-3

Say I'm in a jet and start getting pinged by the machine gun fire of a jet directly behind me.  He has me in his cockpit view and without some serious flying...I'm dead.

- What specific maneuvers make it difficult for the enemy pilot to
  follow, and would allow me to shake him?
- What specific maneuvers make it difficult for the enemy pilot to hit me even if he can
  follow?
- What, more generally, can I do to increase my chances of survival?

Comment: Do a [Barrel Roll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_roll#Barrel_roll)!

Comment: I afterburn, pitch up hard, then throttle speed when I come down and mostly find myself behind the enemy if it is a newbie pilot. Skilled pilots can counter that though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of the easiest moves to do is:

- Brake hard (but not so hard that you stall)
- [Roll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_dynamics) left or right so that you're somewhere between 45-80 degrees off horizontal.
- [Pitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_dynamics) upwards hard (if your flying controls are reversed, you'd be 'pulling back on the stick' at this point)
- Max the throttle and afterburners (making sure that the path forward is clear)

This will quickly take you out of an enemy pilot's field of vision.  If you continue the slow turn, and they don't immediately chase you, you'll be in a good position to get around behind them.  You can also do various [rolls or loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerobatic_maneuver), or [combat maneuvers](http://library.thinkquest.org/3142/manuv.htm), but since this is a video game, realistically what you want to do is change your course frequently.  Even small course changes can really hurt the accuracy of other players.  Matching speed can also be tricky in dogfighting, so change your speed up frequently.

Also remember that their focus is going to be on *you* and your focus is on *flying* - so challenge their flying skill by flying low to the ground or near obstacles.  They'll have to choose between trying to keep you in their sights and avoiding a crash.

Comment: "Challenge their flying skill by flying low to the ground or near obstacles. They'll have to choose between trying to keep you in their sights and avoiding a crash." - Pro tip right there!

Answer (score 7):

If you're up against a skilled pilot, the only way you're going to shake them is to be extremely unpredictable.

This means rolling in weird directions and turning more than they expect etc.

The easiest way I've found to do this (apart from just slowing down and hoping they overshoot you) is to do the following:

Roll left, but keep rolling until you're vertical, but with your jet's top facing to the right (i.e. roll 270 degrees, so it's like you rolled 90 degrees right) then pitch downwards so that you start turning left. Since pitching down is much slower than pitching up, begin to roll left in the middle of your turn and pitch upwards into a loop. At the top of your loop pick a direction (left or right) and roll and turn that way.

If you do that properly and you haven't lost him yet then he's either too far behind you for you to be able to lose him, or he's a very very skilled pilot.

Another thing you can do if you have a good Anti-Air on your team is to fly towards your AA, but doing so not in a straight line (or they can easily shoot you). If you fly close enough to your AA, then they should be able to take out the jet that's chasing you, or the enemy jet will come off your tail in fear of dying.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on altitude. If you are fairly high try a split-S. Google these maneuvers BTW. If you're close to the ground, hit your brakes hard. Pitch straight up. Once you get 90 degrees check your HUD for angle of attack. Barrel roll to left or right. That should get them off your tail and you should be able to get around behind them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try entering a 'turning fight', depending on your aircraft vs enemy maneuverability. If you know that your plane can win a turning fight, try it.

Comment: This would be good advice if I'm in a zero fighting a p-51 in a game with solid flight physics.  However, BF3 aerial combat is not that deep.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a half loop and then turn 90 degreed. Keep rolling in multiples of 90 degrees until you're about to hit the ground, then finish with a full loop.

Comment: Wouldn't a full loop as you're about to hit the ground result in you hitting the ground?

Answer (score 0):

roll a 190 (slightly off horizontal to fool him your going to loop down or make him think your trying to trick him) then you go up or down this time go down. Now brake soft try to stay 190 but even out if have to prevent a crash. Now as your pitching down hit the ecm jammer and it should be hitting his view in the cockpit. The enemy is going to expect you to loop or turn into your roll, don't. Reverse your roll near the end of your ecm now loop in the direction of your but insure your going up at the end and break hard and barrel roll by starting pitching down and make the barrel roll steep and short and go up not for long though the pilot could recover and finish if the enemy turned back into you with a half loop turn called immelman turn and if you break accordingly you should be behind the enemy plane. Note if the enemy did not turn into you dive and finish him.-Most important thing in dogfights is the pilots ingenuity every fight is different and you need to access the situation and fight by changing your strategy in to a unique one to survive -pro tipper